# Using underbrace for long formulas

Tags: tabularx, underbrace

I am trying to use the \underbrace function to define some variables, but the problem here is that the formulas are super long, thus the whole thing cannot be displayed on a single line. I think a possible solution could be to split the formula in 2 lines but I can't find a way to do so, could you give me some advice please? Thank you! Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e, array,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{$}l<{$} |  >{$}L<{$} @{}}
  \text{Cases} & \text{Values of } \Delta_{\alpha} \\
   \hline
   x_1 < x_2, y_1, y_2 & \alpha - \big[\underbrace{w_{22'} + \mu(1)(R_{\max} - w_{21'} - w_{22'}) +  \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'})}_{\alpha_1} \big]\\
   x_2 < x_1, y_1, y_2 & \alpha - \big[\underbrace{R_{\max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{12'} - R_{\max}) + \nu(1)(w_{11'} - w_{12'})}_{\alpha_2}\big] \\
   y_1 < x_1, x_2, y_2 & \alpha - \big[\underbrace{w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'}  - w_{22'}) + \nu(1)(R_{\max} - w_{12'} - w_{22'})}_{\alpha_3} \big] \\
   y_2 < x_1, x_2, y_1 & \alpha - \big[\underbrace{R_{\max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} - w_{21'}) + \nu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{21'} - R_{\max})}_{\alpha_4} \big]  \\
   x_1 = y_1 < x_2 = y_2 & \alpha - \big[\underbrace{w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (R_{\max} - w_{21'} - w_{12'})}_{\alpha_5}\big]\\ 
   x_1 = y_2 < x_2 = y_1 & \alpha - \big[\underbrace{w_{22'} + \mu(1)(R_{\max} - w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} + w_{22'} - R_{\max})}_{\alpha_6}\big]\\
   x_2 = y_1 < x_1 = y_2 & \alpha - \big[\underbrace{w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(R_{\max} - w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} + w_{22'} - R_{\max})}_{\alpha_7}\big] \\
   x_2 = y_2 < x_1 = y_1 & \alpha - \big[\underbrace{R_{\max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{12'} - R_{\max}) + \nu(1')(w_{11'} + w_{21'} - R_{\max}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (R_{\max} - w_{12'} - w_{21'})}_{\alpha_8}\big] \\
   x_1 = x_2 = y_1 = y_2 & \alpha - \big[\underbrace{w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} + w_{22'} - w_{12'} - w_{21'})}_{\alpha_9} \big]
 \end{tabularx} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wait no sorry I edited my code, I  had tried this but it obviously didn't work

Comment: Oh yeah I see, I'm trying to edit it as a test document sorry

Comment: It should work now, but I don't know how I can display it in the question..

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence \text` (I fixed it this time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `array` environment within your formula:

```
...
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{$}l<{$} |  >{$}L<{$} @{}}
  \text{Cases} & \text{Values of } \Delta_{\alpha} \\
  \hline
   x_1 < x_2, y_1, y_2 & \alpha - \underbrace{\left[
     \begin{array}{l}
       w_{22'} + \mu(1)(R_{\max} - w_{21'} - w_{22'}) \\ 
       +\,\nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'})
     \end{array}
  \right]}_{\alpha_1}
\end{tabularx}
...
```

This leads to:

[image]

I changed `\big[` and `\big]` to `\left[` and `\right]` and also moved the underbrace in a way that it also includes the brackets. This results in a visually more appealing output, because the brackets are adjusted perfectly to the (now two-lined) sub-formula.

Please also note that you may want to add additional space for operators at the beginning of a new line (like I did with `+\,\nu(1') ...` in the second line of the `array`, which I added an `\,` spacing to).

Comment: Yes that's perfect, thank you very much!